# djngo account register match with Users app

Tags: django, account

One of the two apps I created in my Django project is accounts and the other is Users. Accounts allows users to register, log in and log out. The Users app creates a user page using their information. How can I import the information of the user registered in the Accounts app to the app in Users?

how can I do some one if registered automatically create I new user in Users app
how can I access this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can import information of the user registered in the Accounts app into Users App. You do this by importing the model class i.e

```
from accounts.models import Account
#rest of code
```

To automatically create a user page when one registers in the accounts app, you will may use [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/signals/) and make use of the `post_save` method to achieve what you are looking for.